# Reusing listview fragment among different layouts and onclick actions

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I have a ListView Fragment that displays items with each item calling custom activity on click.

For example..

```
FragmentA extends Fragment {
  ListViewAdapter -> populates with row layout A, listview layout A.
  ListView onClick -> calls custom Activity A
}
```

Now, I'd like to define similar **FragmentB** but with all different row/listview layout as well as different activity in onClick.

```
FragmentB extends Fragment {
  ListViewAdapter -> populates with row layout B, listview layout B.
  ListView onClick -> calls custom Activity B
}
```

I'm looking for best approach for this case.

Is is better to somehow make **FragmentA** generic and switch layouts/onclicks implementation based on input parameter(Perhaps through Constructor?)

Or should I just make new **FragmentB**? (layout **A** and **B** contain same type of information, just the degree of details are different. A-details, B-simple)

Comment: This could be realized by using the `RecyclerView` with different `view types` and therefore different `layout row files`. The best approach depends on you requirements, would the `List` be the only changed element, I'd recommend the above approach. If there is more to change, use 2 different `Fragments`.

Comment: This can be done with one generic fragment, you would use callbacks to the parent activities to do stuff specific to each activity. But on the other hand it may be simpler to make them seperate. Also have you seen [ListFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html) ?

Comment: Thank you for the answers, my requirement is to display different list item objects(say A and B) which in turn exhibit different onClick actions(calling custom activity A and B), so more than one variable here. It sounds like going for separate Fragment is the approach I should take. I was wondering if there could be more componentized way allowing users specify individual listview objects and onClick behaviors on one general purpose fragment, rather than making a specific fragment with fixed item/onClicks but that might be going too further.